# App Domains error from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ads, appdomain

I have created new app in Facebook for running campaigns(app installs). Under app settings, while setting the value(app store link of the iOS app) for app domains, it throws the below mentioned error.

**App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: itunes.apple.com**

I have added both iOS & android platforms and mentioned the required info over there. But app domains still throws the above mentioned error.

Anyone has faced the same issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.